# What unit of measure does Paint.setStrokeWidth() use?

Tags: android

What unit of measure does Paint.setStrokeWidth() use and do I need to scale this value based on the current screen density?

It's a float value so I know it's not a number of pixels. It must be relative to something.

This is all the documentation says as of this writing:

> Set the width for stroking. Pass 0 to stroke in hairline mode. Hairlines always draws a single pixel independent of the canva's matrix.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The stroke width is defined in pixels (yes it's a float, and there's no problem with using fractions of pixels :)

Comment: Hi Romain,  I've tried PathEffect example from ApiDemos and the stroke width is set to 6 there. When I measure the width on my hdpi mobile phone screen it is 9px. It looks like the initial stroke width value is multiplied by the density. Should I provide the value divided by density in order to get real width?

Comment: I don't believe Romain's answer is correct. On my current test device (HTC One X, with density of 2.0) I've found that `.setStrokeWidth()` must be called with the desired stroke width divided by 1.5. Then, the width is exactly as it should be. Otherwise, it's too wide. The 1.5 factor agrees exactly with what Zzokk found (6px vs 9px), except I question if it is density related, because the One X is 2.0, not 1.5. So the origin of this 1.5 factor is puzzling me at the moment.

Comment: Damn!! I just came here to solve this doubt. I saw @Romain Guy answering and I thought "We have the answer for sure", but then in the comments it doesn't seem so easy.


Anyway I have tried to just deal with it like if it where pixels like converting from dp to pixels... and it seems to be working for different screen sizes...

Comment: Have you guys turn off anti alias? Note that, if you expect 1 pixel width line, rectangle stroke, ... you need to turn off anti alias.

Comment: Note that stroke width is affected by the transformations attached to the canvas. If you call canvas.scale(2.0f, 2.0f) the stroke width will also be multiplied by 2.0.

Comment: To add a bit of clarification, the reason why it's not documented is because *every* Java Android API takes pixels (except, for some reason, stuff related to text size) so it's implicit.

Comment: I believe stroke width is subject to scaling. So if you don't specify a scale factor or transformation matrix, then it's in pixels. If you've set scaling, then it's in pixels times the scale factor.

Answer (score 29):

setStrokeWidth uses pixels.

So to convert you dps to pixels for painting:

```
int dpSize =  10;
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics() ;
float strokeWidth = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dpSize, dm);
paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
```

Comment: Or you could stick the value where in belongs - dimens.xml and then simply do this: paint.setStrokeWidth(getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.stroke_width));

Comment: This still doesn't work, my strokes all appear different on different devices, anyone fixed it ??

Comment: @slott the value could have been calculated dynamically, so it won't be in dimens.xml.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to keep in mind if you're attempting to `onDraw` your own "canvas border" is that *even the stroke is clipped*. So

```
paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
rect.set(0, 0, width, height)
paint.strokeWidth = 10F
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint)
```

will result in a "border" that is only 5F wide. This is due to the stroke being *centered* over the rect, which in this case is the edge of the canvas - resulting in half of it actually being clipped as it's outside the canvas.

To fix this, simply multiply your desired boarder thickness by 2. [In the example above, you'd set `strokeWidth = 20F` and you'd "see" a stroke of 10F.]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the thing I was wondering about where I tried to draw a rect of 1dp, but it looked too narrow. I couldn't figure it out, but this would explain it. Quite confusing actually...