# Android drawing position on view

Tags: android, view, draw

As I am a beginner of Android developement, I need someone to give me an answer or any comments on my question.

When I draw a simple rectangle on a view with the following code, the rectangle doesn't show in the way in which I would expect.

```
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), framePaint);
```

wrong

[image]

But when I changed it like this, it shows properly.

```
canvas.drawRect(1, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()-1, framePaint);
```

Correct

[image]

That looks like the left and the bottom lines are clipped out of the view.
I was expecting that the position of view starts zero-indexed such as 0 ~ (size of view)-1. Do I understand wrong or did i do something wrong?

The framePaint is configured like this;

```
framePaint = new Paint();
framePaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
framePaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
framePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

Comment: From what I've tried (maybe someone will prove me wrong), the stroke is always aligned to the center of your shape's edges and doesn't count into your shape's width, so you have to account for this fact when you're positioning the element. Other than that, you can also pass 0 to `setStrokeWidth` to get a hairline, single-pixel width stroke which isn't scaled depending on the screen density.

Comment: @Ace_McIntosh Thanks for the reply. yes. setStrokeWidth with 0 works. I am still confused that the issue lies on the stroke with the density. I might need to read carefully the reference or books relating to this...

Comment: OK, according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789806/what-unit-of-measure-does-paint-setstrokewidth-use) the `setStrokeWidth` takes in the number of pixels so it's density independent either way (even with arguments greater than zero) – sorry for making you confused, I shouldn't have pointed that out for this particular value when it's true for any value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens:

When you subtract one from the total pixels, it draws the line(s) in the image, not outside of it.

Also the "1" at the start also helps the code stay in the canvas.

You may want to try replacing the 1's in the code with 2's, as the canvas uses an extra pixel to automatically remove "aliasing".